# Determining the rate of change of a radius as a sphere loses volume

Tags: calculus, derivatives, volume

**Problem:**

A spherical balloon leaks $0.2\mathrm m^3 / \mathrm{min}$.

How fast does the radius of the balloon decrease the moment the radius is $0.5\mathrm m$?

**My progress:**

Since we're dealing with the rate of change of the volume, I set up a function for volume wrt. the radius, which would be $$V(r) = \frac43\pi r^3$$

Then I differentiated it, and got $$V'(r) = 4\pi r^2$$

Now, I don't know quite how to use the first piece of information in the problem. Am I going to need to find a $V(t)$ here? As far as I can tell, we can say that $$V'(t) = -0.2$$ but how do I piece all this together? (Assuming I'm right so far.)

Any help appreciated!

Comment: You did not differentiate correctly. Notice that both the volume and radius are functions of time, i.e. use implicit differentiation which  gives you $$ V'(t) = \frac43 \pi r^2 r'(t)$$

Comment: You differentiated correctly with respect to $r$. You need to differentiate with respect to $t$ instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At all times, $V=\frac43 \pi r^3$.  So $\frac{dV}{dt}=4\pi r^2 \frac{dr}{dt}$.

At the moment of interest, you have a value for the radius and a value for $\frac{dV}{dt}$ (be careful here--the volume is decreasing).  This should allow you to plug into the derivative equation above and find $\frac{dr}{dt}$ at the moment of interest.

Comment: Ah, I forgot the chain rule! Solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You started correctly with
$$
V = \frac{4}{3} \pi r^3
$$
But your time derivative misses $\dot{r}$, that is the quantity you want
$$
\dot{V} = 4 \pi r^2 \dot{r} \iff
\dot{r} = \frac{\dot{V}}{4\pi r^2}
$$ 
You had 
$\dot{V} = -0.2 \,\mbox{m}^3/\mbox{min} = \mbox{const}$
and $r = 0.5 \,\mbox{m}$ which gives
$$
\dot{r} = -0.064 \,\mbox{m}/\mbox{min}
$$